# undo content disposition and output contents to a file on server?

Tags: php, file-io, truetype

The following code is the original and taken from the DOMPDF library: FontLib. it can handle the sub-setting of a .ttf font, i have been trying to adapt this piece of code to my basic needs, unfortunately i could not get the code running as i wanted to.. i have the following questions that could help me continue!

How can i edit this piece of code so it will not force a download but instead save it to the server?

I have tried the following to disable the force download,

Disabling the header content-disposition wont fully disable its action, it will trigger a new download with the actual content in binary code, why does it do this? perhaps the function readfile() has to do something with this issue, in my understanding it will output contents into the output-buffer and display it. How can i prevent from doing so and store it with file_put_contents() ?

```
if (isset($_POST["subset"])) {  
  $subset = $_POST["subset"];  

  ob_start();

  require_once "../src/FontLib/Autoloader.php";

  $font = Font::load($fontfile);  
  $font->parse();

  $font->setSubset($subset);  
  $font->reduce();

  $new_filename = basename($fontfile);  
  $dot = strpos($new_filename, ".");  
  $new_filename = substr($new_filename, 0, $dot)."-subset".substr($new_filename, $dot);

  header("Content-Type: font/truetype");  
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$new_filename\"");

  $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "fnt");  
  $font->open($tmp, Binary_Stream::modeWrite);  
  $font->encode(array("OS/2"));  
  $font->close();

  ob_end_clean();

  readfile($tmp);  
  unlink($tmp);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple things you should be aware of:

[readfile](http://www.php.net/readfile) - Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer. 
[unlink](http://www.php.net/unlink) - Used to remove files.

Your code above is creating a temporary file, using the readline function to send the contents of that file to the output buffer, and and then promptly removing the file once the entire file has been buffered. If you don't want to server the file, remove the calls to header, readline and unlink. The path to the file that you want is stored in the $tmp variable already, so you can manipulate it as needed.